# IBM Worklight not working in Eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to evaluate IBM Worklight, however Eclipse 3.7.2 is not displaying any of the functionality that is supposed to be provided by the IBM Worklight plug-ins.

I installed Worklight from the Eclipse Marketplace and have verified that the plug-ins are actually listed under "About Eclipse SDK". My eclipse.ini is as follows:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.101.v20120109-1504
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms100m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m   
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

I have also tried appending -clean to the above list as well as restarting Eclipse, changing workspaces etc. However I'm still totally unable to see Worklight in my toolbar or create Worklight Projects.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

**Update:** Added workspace log for a fresh workspace.

> !SESSION 2012-07-13 14:44:27.572
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.6.0_33 java.vendor=Apple
>   Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
>   Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring
>   -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -data /Users/ben/Projects/eclipse/worklight -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-13 14:44:31.545 !MESSAGE
>   System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
>   local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
>   value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-07-13 14:47:09.927 !MESSAGE Unhandled
>   event loop exception !STACK 0 org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Device is
>   disposed  at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1065)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:619)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getShells(Display.java:1704)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler.execute(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:66)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410) !SESSION
>   2012-07-13 14:47:14.118
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.6.0_33 java.vendor=Apple
>   Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
>   Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring
>   -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-13 14:47:19.044 !MESSAGE
>   System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
>   local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
>   value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
>   !SESSION 2012-07-13 14:48:38.988
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.6.0_33 java.vendor=Apple
>   Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
>   Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring
>   -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-13 14:48:42.586 !MESSAGE
>   System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
>   local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
>   value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
>   !SESSION 2012-07-13 14:49:29.076
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.6.0_33 java.vendor=Apple
>   Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
>   Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring
>   -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-13 14:49:32.650 !MESSAGE
>   System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
>   local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
>   value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
>   !SESSION 2012-07-13 14:49:47.302
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.6.0_33 java.vendor=Apple
>   Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
>   Framework arguments:  -showsplash org.eclipse.platform
>   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m --launcher.defaultAction openFile -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -showsplash
>   org.eclipse.platform --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
>   --launcher.defaultAction openFile -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-13 14:49:50.918 !MESSAGE
>   System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
>   local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
>   value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
>   !SESSION 2012-07-13 14:52:52.544
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.6.0_33 java.vendor=Apple
>   Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
>   Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring
>   -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/ben/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-13 14:52:55.949 !MESSAGE
>   System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to
>   local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This
>   value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

**Update 2:** Based on the little information I can find this may be caused by some sort of incompatibility with the latest Android Developer Tools (ADT 20). This is some-what concerning considering Worklight is designed to work in conjunction with ADT.

Comment: Is there anything shown in the Error Log View (or your workspace's .metadata/.log file) that could indicate a problem?

Comment: @nitind - I've attached a log above. org.eclipse.swt.SWTException doesn't sound great, but it doesn't seem related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with Eclipse Classic (3.7.2) and Worklight and ADT 20. ADT 20 was released after the current version of Worklight was released.

As a workaround you can install Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Eclipse Indigo or Helios, but not the latest version Juno, which was also released after the current version of Worklight was released).

Comment: Actually, I am working with Eclipse Juno and Worklight and they are working great together.
The bug happens when you install Worklight after insalling ADT 20.
So install a clean Eclipse, install Worklight and then install ADT 20.